# Trim and concatenation of string from two column: python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have tried a ton of ways but none of worked! I would greatly appreciate if someone give any solutions or suggestions.

I have a `df` of 2 column.

```
|       | col 1   | col 2 |
|-------|---------|-------|
| row 1 | ε       | A     |   
| row 2 | aa/#/00 | ε     |   
| row 3 | ε       | B     |   
| row 4 | bb/#/11 | ε     |   
|  ...  |   ...   |  ...  |  
|  ...  |   ...   |  ...  |
```

Now I want to generate a string. for example,

```
00A
```

here `00` is from `(col, row) = (1,2)`
and `A` is from `(col, row) = (2,1)`

another example is

```
11B
```

I want to get all the strings as possible from the `df`.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you can index the str and concatenate the shift of 1 row.

```
import pandas as pd


data = {
    "col1": ["E", "aa/#/00", "E", "bb/#/11"],
    "col2": ["A", "E", "B", "E"]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df["generated"] = df["col1"].str[-2:] + df["col2"].shift(1)
print(df)

      col1 col2 generated
0        E    A       NaN
1  aa/#/00    E       00A
2        E    B        EE
3  bb/#/11    E       11B
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted! Thanks man!... 
if you don;t mind can you briefly explain
`df["col1"].str[-2:] + df["col2"].shift(1)` this part of the code!

Comment: df["col1"].str[-2:]
Indexes the last 2 chars from col1 column.

df["col2"].shift(1) 
shifts down 1 row and uses that value in col2

Comment: as i have to implement it on my actual `df`, it's important to understand for me. Thanks you very much. :)